# Reverse a number program not working,why?

Tags: c++, numbers, reverse

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

  int n,sum=0;
  cout<<"enter no.";
  cin>>n;

  while(n!=0)
  {
      int r=n%10;
      int sum= (sum*10)+r;
      n=n/10;
  }
cout<<sum;
return 0;

}
```

here output should reverse a number but it is giving o/p as '0'
can't understand y!!
plz help.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and more [about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Enable all warnings and debug info in your C++ compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Count the number of variable definitions for `sum`.

Comment: Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* service. Read about [semantics of programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), and perhaps [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't read a number, read a string:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

  std::string n;
  cout<<"enter no.";
  cin>>n;

  std::string reversed(n.rbegin(), n.rend());

  cout<<reversed;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Code was basically correct but there was a minor mistake you made in while loop.
**Old Code:-**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

  int n,sum=0;
  cout<<"enter no.";
  cin>>n;

  while(n!=0)
  {
      int r=n%10;         //-- Y R U declaring the variables 'r' and 'sum' here?
      int sum= (sum*10)+r;//-- Declare them at top and initialize 'sum' with 0
      n=n/10;
  }
cout<<sum;
return 0;

}
```

**New Code:-**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number >> ";
    cin >> n;

    while (n != 0) {
        sum = (sum * 10) + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter a number >> 123456
654321
Press any key to continue . . . _
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `int` before `sum` was creating a local variable inside your loop that was hiding the outer `sum`. If you remove it, your program will work. You may want to look up *scoping* for C++ variables.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

  int n,sum=0;
  cout<<"enter no.";
  cin>>n;

  while(n!=0)
  {
      int r = n % 10;
      sum = (sum * 10) + r;
      //^^ note no int
      n=n/10;
  }
  cout<<sum;
  return 0;
}
```